# Removing element from array in java, without import

Tags: java, arrays, import

I'm trying to learn Java, while playing around with it, and a friend of mine claims it is possible to remove an element from an array, in only a few lines, without importing anything.

I have been racking my head around how said procedure can be done, and this is what I've come up with.

```
public void removeStudent(Student student) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if(list[i].getID() == student.getID()) {
            for (int j = i; j < list.length; j++) {
                int y = j;
                list[i] = list[y++];
                studentsThusFar--;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My thinking is I can remove a Student object by moving all object after it one space up. But wouldn't that fall apart if the last object in the array was to be the one removed?

Please keep your answers precise and use language a beginner could understand.

Comment: you know the length of the array... check to see the number of elements left... check if the element to be removed is the last one.. if yes, do nothing after removing it. otherwise, from the position(its called index not space :) ), start moving your data one index/cell up... Your approach is correct.

Comment: @TheLostMind 
So how would I go about removing the last element in said array? After I've either moved everything up, or discovered that the desired deletion was the last element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply copy all items to a new array, except the item to-be-removed. Then return the new array.

```
public void removeStudent(Student student) {
    int[] new_list = new Student[list.length-1];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if(list[i].getID() != student.getID()) {
            new_list[j] = list[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    list = new_list; //Assuming list is some global
}
```

Comment: Functional, no doubt, but as you see, my method is void, so I'm wanting to modify an existing table and not return a new one... thanks anyway though!

Comment: then replace the variable list with new_list... updating answer

Comment: @Chiel92 - You cant remove an element from an array.. you just set it to null(in case o objects) and 0 for int ( in your case) and so on...

Comment: @TheLostMind I did not know that. Learned something new today. Thank you too mate.

Comment: @Chiel92 - Sorry man.. Got confused between Ur name and OP's name ..Commented at the wrong place...  :P